# This helps to understand something

Tags: word-usage

Should it be

> This helps understand something

Or

> This helps to understand something

Note that it is not

> This helps us understand something,

although this is what I want to express.

Comment: Thanks to your last qualifier, it's not clear what you're really looking for.

Comment: More context (in full sentences) is needed. You shouldn't use vague/variable type words like *something* because the usage might change based on what "something" is.

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate. As user3169 said, the full sentence is needed

Comment: @user178049 That's why you flagged it as a **possible** duplicate. (: